# Can't apply simple hide function on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, show-hide

***EDIT: This is for leaning purpose***

I have jQuery library included in my header:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

In body I have simple div:

```
<div id="image">
    <img class="width" src="assets/images/janka.jpg">
</div>
```

And at the end of body is simple script:

```
<script>
    $("#image").load(function () { 
        $("#image").hide();         
    });
</script>
```

I would like to hide "image" div after loaded by jQuery function hide(). But nothing happens after page is loaded, div is still visible. In browser console is no error shown. Can't find out what I'm doing wrong. Pls, correct my banal error there.

Comment: just use plain css to hide the div using `display: none`

Comment: @VDesign: `.hide();` does the same.

Comment: ok, but I want to learn jQuery, it doesnt matter what function it is.

Comment: So does the onload handler fired? I guess no... You have to learn how to debug javascript before going further

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I now but if he just wants to hide it css can do the trick

Comment: Why does haters downvote my question, when I doesn't understand something. It is wrong formulation of question or what?

Comment: @VDesign: seriously?? `.hide()` is equivalent for `.css('display','none')`. or are you referring to use pure CSS?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I was indeed pointing to use css styles not `.css(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

load can be called on Body,iframe,img etc. but not on divs, Instead if you wish to use onload event on an element, you need to bind it with the element for eg. with div.But basically  there are 2 ways to call a function
      1. is to call function just after div load , write just after div element

```
       <div id="image">
            <img class="width" src="assets/images/janka.jpg">
    </div>

<script>
   function toHide() { 
        $("#image").hide();         
    }
    toHide();
    </script>
```

2. is to fire function onload of img instead of div

```
    $("#image img").load(function () { 
                $("#image img").hide();     //USING JS function    
            });
        OR



         $("#image").load(function () { 
                $("#image").css('display', 'none');     //USING CSS   
            });
```

Comment: `load can be called on Body,iframe,img etc. but certainly not on div.` ***As a side note:*** you can bind onload event to the DIV if you wish to **capture onload event** of any of its children

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, that can also be done to achieve the same purpose. :)

Comment: Ya, just setting an example to make my comment more clear: http://jsfiddle.net/2272e62z/

Comment: @A.Wolff that made your point more clear, thanks. BTW nice drawing :)

Answer (score 1):

The `#image` element is a `div` which does not raise the `load` event. You need to select the `img` element inside that which does raise the event:

```
$("#image img").load(function () { 
    $("#image").hide();         
});
```

Comment: there will be more functionality, i was just wondering why it doesnt work

Comment: @A.Wolff ah ok, I missed that. If it's a learning exercise then go nuts :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be img:

```
$("#image img").load(function () { 
        $("#image img").hide();         
    });
```

The load of the div can't be checked but images can be. If you want to hide div right after html is ready then use ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#image').hide();
});
```

But you're using the script at the end of closing body you just apply this:

```
$('#image').hide();
```