# Issues in onload function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with shopify store.
I have created to show fancy box when entered my website.

This is code i used:

```
<div id="wrap"><div id="step1"></div>
            <pre onclick="not1()">{}</pre>        
</div>




 <script>
            function not1(){
                notif({
                    msg: "&lt;b&gt;Success:&lt;/b&gt; In 5 seconds i'll be gone",
                    type: "success"
                });
            }
    </script>
```

And i used notifIt.js and jquery.js files. Now its working fine, I have taken code from this site http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Easy-jQuery-Notification-Plugin-NotifIt/

Instead of click the text box, i need to show that notification box automatically.

So i changed above script onclick to onload.. but nothing seems to be work

May i know, what is my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is this ---><span class="f">notif(</span>{
  msg: <span class="s">"&lt;b&gt;Success:&lt;/b&gt; In 5 seconds i'll be gone"</span>,
  type: <span class="s">"success"</span>
}<span class="f">)</span>;

Comment: I don't understand it's meaning

Comment: You will need to get rid of `onload` and possibly substitute jQuery's `$(window).load`.  `onload` is not compatible with jQuery.

Comment: @RishiPrakash: it is just message, when we click this message, it will show pop up and it hide automatically

Comment: @RishiPrakash: when see this link: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Easy-jQuery-Notification-Plugin-NotifIt/, when click first box, it will show green color box right, so i need without i click that box , need to green box display automatically and hide automatically..

Comment: ok @BobBrown: how can i modify my code?

Comment: @BobBrown: can you please help me?

Comment: @selva:  That will have to wait for someone to write code for an answer.

Comment: This is my code and output: http://runnable.com/me/VJ1JBwNXKGQBgeK2

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show your notification on page loading?

If you do, you can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    not1();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call Your function, directly. It will be called automatically on script tag loading.

```
 <div id="wrap"><div id="step1"></div>
                <pre onclick="not1()">{}</pre>        
    </div>




     <script>
                function not1(){
                    notif({
                        msg: "&lt;b&gt;Success:&lt;/b&gt; In 5 seconds i'll be gone",
                        type: "success"
                    });
                }
    not1(); //CALLING FUNCTION, It will be called automatically. I hope it would help.
        </script>
```

For reference see [Can't apply simple hide function on div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618267/cant-apply-simple-hide-function-on-div/27618429#27618429)